# Why am I recieving this error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_core246d.lib''?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv, linker-errors

I am trying to run a program that does not include any opencv files, but for some reason this error keeps popping up and preventing me from running the program.

> LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_core246d.lib'        C:\Users\Public\Documents\imgSwitchingFiles

Please can somebody shed light on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your project options state this library should be linked to your binaries. Did you reuse this project from elsewhere?

If you really don't need OpenCV, simply remove its libraries from the project linking options.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where can I find the project linking options?

Comment: On the project properties you'll find it. You are looking for something like "input", under a section most probably called "link" or something similar. There you most likely will find references to the opencv libraries. Just remove them. I'm sorry not to be able to give you any more precise directions, but I don't have msvc easily accessible here, I don't even have windows easily accessible at the moment, moreover it's been quite a while since the last time I used it.

Answer (score 0):

In project properties:

```
   VC++ Directories>Library files>C:\OpenCV2.4.3\build\x86\vc9\lib
```

&

```
    Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies>
```

Add the following under edit (each on a new line)

opencv_core243d.lib; opencv_imgproc243d.lib; opencv_highgui243d.lib; opencv_ml243d.lib; opencv_video243d.lib; opencv_features2d243d.lib; opencv_calib3d243d.lib; opencv_objdetect243d.lib; opencv_contrib243d.lib; opencv_legacy243d.lib; opencv_flann243d.lib;

Your file paths may be different i.e. vc10 instead of vc9 or u may have x64 instead of x86.
Also u will have 246 in every .lib instead of 243.